# What's the main difference between encrypting programs and creating encrypted archives?

Tags: encryption, archiving

For example which encryption is stronger? a truecrypt  volume or an encrypted  7zip archive (using the same passwords)

Comment: The answer depends on way to many variables

Comment: Do  encryption programs do something more that what is done by eg  7zip?